# Unable to connect to database name containing square bracket character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

I am having a database named `[]my[]database` in SQL Server.

I have tried through following ways to connect to the database. But none of the queries working out.

`use []my[]database`

`use "[]my[]database"`

`use "\[]my\[]database"`

`use QUOTENAME("[]my[]database")`

`use [[]]my[]]database]`

Is there any mistake in my syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a database name that contains SQL Server special characters? That just seems perverse. Use a better name.

Comment: the last one works for me in SSMS, when creating a test db named `[]my[]database` in SQL Server 2017. what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

[`Use`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) requires a database name and does not accept an expression, e.g. `use QuoteName( '[]my[]database' );`.

The result of `select QuoteName( '[]my[]database' );` is `[[]]my[]]database]`, so `use [[]]my[]]database];` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double square brackets to escape them

`````
````
USE [[][my[]database]
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
use [[]]my[]]database]
```

Comment: I tried this. But this one also not working